# New feature "Answer similar questions" - bug? same question I just answered offered as top choice

Tags: bug, status-completed, answer-similar-questions

On the new feature "Answer similar questions" -  is this a bug?

I got the same question I just answered offered as top choice to answer as my next question? if It is a bug how do I report it?

Comment: To be fair, that question was certainly very similar.

Comment: "if It is a bug how do I report it?" - you just did.

Comment: This is a race condition, the search index is lagging a bit too much and returning an answered question even though there's already a "don't return answered questions" constraint.  Digging...

Answer (score 7):

I've just deployed a change that should fix this.

The search querying being run already excludes questions with any answers, so this can only occur when the timing's just right and the search runs before the index updates.  The latest build explicitly excludes the answered question from the search, regardless of whether or not the index things it's answered.

Comment: yay! you rock, thanks for your hard work on this feature! I really like the idea.